# jQuery & SharePoint - Hide field when checkbox unchecked

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am working with a custom SharePoint new form and need to hide/show some fields based on the value of a choice field (set to allow multiple selections - checkboxes).

I am quite new to using jQuery, but have managed to hide the fields initially and even show the fields when the appropriate checkbox is selected, but I need the associated checkbox to hide itself again if the checkbox becomes unchecked. I have added an else statement on one of the checkboxes and it works great, but when I add the same else statement to the another checkbox, all of the fields show up again on. I assume that I am breaking the script.

Here is what I have done so far and would appreciate any help!

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   try {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            _resizeModalDialog();
        }
    }
    catch (err) { }
    
 $(document).ready(function()
  {
           //Hide Name fields initially
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('New Employment Type')").closest("tr").hide();
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('New Job Position')").closest("tr").hide();
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('New Salary')").closest("tr").hide();


     //Associate a function with Drop down change event
  $("[id$='TypeofRequest_cd29aee6-a80d-46a1-8c44-5e3046a5db8a_MultiChoiceOption_0']").change(function()
    {
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (checked)
         {
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('New Employment Type')").closest("tr").fadeIn(600);
         }
     });
     
     //Associate a function with Drop down change event
  $("[id$='TypeofRequest_cd29aee6-a80d-46a1-8c44-5e3046a5db8a_MultiChoiceOption_1']").change(function()
    {
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (checked)
         {
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('New Job Position')").closest("tr").fadeIn(600);
  }
  else
  {
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('New Job Position')").closest("tr").hide(600);
         }
     });
   
  //Associate a function with Drop down change event
  $("[id$='TypeofRequest_cd29aee6-a80d-46a1-8c44-5e3046a5db8a_MultiChoiceOption_2']").change(function()
    {
        var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (checked)
         {
    $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('New Salary')").closest("tr").fadeIn(600);
         }
     });
 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: provide your html markups please

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but I am not sure what you are referring to :) Could you please clarify? I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: show us your html